# Python Extend a Class from a Module

Tags: python-2.7, class

I've made a lot of search but I can't find a way to extend a class from a module.

I have an installed module that has 3 files init, config, core & errors. All the class methods are defined in "core", but the variables are defined in "config".

I need to add another method and some new values to variables, but I wasn't able to make it works.

I've tried to do something like:

```
class newFunctions(oldClass):
    old_variable = {'newkey':'value'}

    def __init__(self,original_value):
        self.original_value = original value

    # now comes my new function:
    def new_function(self,newkey):
        url = _some_function_from_original_class(newkey)
```

Well this way doesn't work, have to used the original source class. I changed:

```
        url = oldClass._some_function_from_original_class(newkey)
```

Damn... this give me the following error:

```
  File ".py", line 41, in new_function
response = oldClass._some_function_from_original_class(newkey)
TypeError: unbound method _some_function_from_original_class() must be called with oldClass instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

I thought that I'll be smarter and quicker if I move the entire _some_function_from_original_class() and declare with the same name in the new class, but got in other errors related to variables! So I'm really lost.

Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code. The exception you show is for a line that's not shown in the code snippet above it, and it seems to suggest that you're calling methods directly on the classes, rather than on instances of them. While that can sometimes make sense, it's not the normal way to use methods! If you just want functions without dealing with instances, you probably don't need a class at all.

Comment: Please read the document for better understanding of [Python Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) and the use of [Class local reference](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references)

Comment: Hmm.... pyCharm corrected my code and after I did the following:

1. Add "from module_name.config import old_variable".
2. Add "from module_name.core import some_other_variables."
3. I moved the _some_function_from_original_class in here but I accessed it using "self._some_function_from_original_class".

And now, it magically works!

Anyway, if anybody have a nicer way to do what I need I would love to see!

Comment: Blckknght and  hcheung thanks for support. I read some stuff about inheritances, I've googled a lot. I believe that the problem is that in module variables were defined outside of the class and then imported the file. Probably.... What I wanted was to "extend" a module with new methods and variables...